# How do I join columns from different Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes with a single column and a common date index. How do I create a THIRD dataframe with the same date index and a copy of both columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df1` and `df2` have the same index:

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2)
```

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. It gives NaN on the values of the second column.

Comment: I am very sorry. The dates are not the same. They have 1 year diference.